# Mudar tamanho da fonte

Tags: html, css, html5, font, css-font-size

Estou a tentar mudar a fonte num documento html, no entanto, se eu indicar o nome da fonte, esta não muda e o tamanho volta ao original.

Este é o codigo que estou a usar:

```
p { 
    padding:20px; 
    background-color: white; 
    font-size: 20px 
    font-family: Helvetica  
}
```

Comment: Poderia postar sua pergunta em Português?

Comment: Duas vezes fui para a página inicial e pensei que tinha entrado no site SOen. Por favor traduza pergunta.

Comment: Eu estou a tentar mudar a fonte num documento html, no entanto, se eu indicar o nome da fonte, esta não muda e o tamanho volta ao original. Este é o codigo que estou a usar:                                                                       p {
    padding:20px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 20px    
    font-family: Helvetica
}

Comment: @SanicSpeed já experimentas-te juntar `;` no final das duas ultimas linhas, defenir a `font-family` antes de `font-size`?

Comment: Ok. Obrigado, pensei que já tivesse tentado isso mas afinal não. Funciunou.

Answer (score 3):

Se colocares os `;` nas duas ultimas linhas como a sintaxe do CSS pede então vai funcionar bem. No CSS quando tens várias linhas/declarações seguidas o uso de `;` é obrigatório. Podes ler mais sobre sintaxe de [regras e seletores CSS na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/sintaxe). Adaptei uma das imagens de lá:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O teu código deve ficar:

```
p {
    padding:20px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

Exemplo de como estava: http://jsfiddle.net/2tj8ur8h/
Exemplo de como deve ficar: http://jsfiddle.net/2tj8ur8h/1/